# How to change div dimensions whenever window dimensions are changed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game for fun and whenever I shrink the window, the div will keep its height and width (I tried using vh and vw, but it was too hard to manipulate in Javascript), making the div fall to the next line of tic tac toe board. Thus, I tried to manipulate the height whenever the window is resized by using a javascript function. Here it is with the rest of the code for the div. Can you tell me how I can improve the code or to make it actually work?

```js
function dimensions() {
  var textHeight = (window.innerHeight * .3333333);
  var textWidth = (window.innerWidth * .32);

  if ((textHeight != window.innerHeight) || (textWidth != window.innerWidth)) {

    document.getElementById("oMark").style.height = textHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById("oMark").style.width = textWidth + "px";
  }
}

dimensions._intervalId = setInterval(dimensions, 1);
```

```css
.O {
  clear: none;
  margin: 0;
  height: 239.999px;
  display: block;
  width: 485.849px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: none;
  float: left;
}
.O:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="oMark" class="O">
  O
</div>
```

Comment: What do mean by "hard to manipulate in Javascript"?

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages for the `width` and `height` of your `div`s, in that way your `div`s sizes will be fluid instead of fixed and will fill the window evenly.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly outlined two options for changing a `div`'s size when the window size changes-- one option is to handle it with CSS, and the other options is to handle it with Javascript.

If your use case is simple, then you can probably get away with CSS-- rather than hardcoding a width and height, style their dimensions with a relative unit like percentages-- this is simple, efficient and fast.

```css
.O {
    clear: none;
    margin: 0;
    height: 50vh;
    display: block;
    width: 90vw;
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: none;
    float: left;

}
.O: hover {
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id = "oMark" class = "O">
                O
                
</div>
```

The CSS option can also be augmented using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for finer control at different viewport sizes.

The other option, if you have found some use case that cannot be accommodated with CSS alone, is to use Javascript.  Now, above you have written a script where you are attempting to do some resizing, but the way you are trying to accomplish it-- by setting a interval that repeats every millisecond, is nightmarish.  You are better off leveraging the [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) DOM event.  A very basic example of how to do this would be:

```
function sayHello () {
    console.log('hello!');
}

window.addEventListener('resize', sayHello);
```

The MDN link above shows ways to optimize the native `resize` event so that it can be more efficient.

I took the liberty of changing your code below to leverage the `resize` event, and fixed the missing close parens on your `if` condition:

```html
<div id = "oMark" class = "O">
                O
                
                <script>
                    
                    function dimensions() {
                        var textHeight = (window.innerHeight*0.3333333);
                        var textWidth = (window.innerWidth*0.32);
                        
                        if ((textHeight != window.innerHeight) || (textWidth != window.innerWidth)) {
                            
                            document.getElementById("oMark").style.height = textHeight+"px";
                            document.getElementById("oMark").style.width = textWidth+"px";
                        }
                    }
                    window.addEventListener('resize', dimensions);
                    
                </script>
                <style>
                    .O
                    {
                        clear: none;
                        margin: 0;
                        height: 239.999px;
                        display: block;
                        width: 485.849px;
                        background-color: lightblue;
                        font-size: 30px;
                        border: 5px solid black;
                        text-align: center;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        overflow: none;
                        float: left;
                        
                    }
                    .O:hover
                    {
                        background-color: blue;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        text-align: center;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                </style>
</div>
```

As for what the rest of your Javascript is attempting to accomplish I can only speculate-- but the above gets it firing on the resize and executing without breaking on an error.